# Change a CSS file programmatically using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Asp.net using c# I am new to this programming language and was wondering if it would be possible to change

```
.main
{
    padding: 0px 12px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    min-height: 630px;
    width:auto;
    background-image:url('background.png');
  }
```

the background image URL based on a button click.. Through then use of C# code based upon a button click

```
protected void initiative_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Session["agency"] = "Initiative";
        }
```

but the main thing is that the CSS file is liked to different page to where the button click is located.

Comment: Can't you do this on the client-side with javascript?

Comment: I have tried and it dont work... so was wondering if it woiuld be possible

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**
Rather than change your CSS file apply different classes based on the session.

```
.main
{
    padding: 0px 12px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    min-height: 630px;
    width:auto;
}

.agency1 { background-image: url('agency1.png'); }
.agency2 { background-image: url('agency2.png'); }
.agency3 { background-image: url('agency3.png'); }
```

Then add two classes to your div

```
<div class="main <%=Session["agency"]%>"></div>
```

**Option 2**
Create a Generic Handler that renders the specific CSS and add that to your page

```
<link href="GenerateCss.ashx" rel="stylesheet" />
```

In your GenerateCss.ashx.cs file you would have something like this

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

        string image = "main";
        if (context.Session != null && context.Session["agency"] != null)
        {
            image = context.Session["agency"].ToString();
        }

        string result = ".main{padding: 0px 12px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; min-height: 630px; width:auto; background-image:url('" + image + ".png');}";
        context.Response.Write(result);
    }
```

**Be extremely careful as this could set you up for an XSS attack if used improperly**  You'll need to make sure that session["agency"] is not user controllable.  By that I mean that the user cannot supply that value as this would allow them to inject anything they want in there.

I don't recommend the second option though because you're going to be calling this for every request and not a good idea to keep generating CSS when you can just make it static.  If you can use option 1, I would say it would be better.

Comment: but the page with the code in never loaded as it on the site.master file#

Comment: Once you click the button that will fire a postback event which will reload the page.  If you base the image name on what is in the session then you will be fine when you navigate to the other page.

Answer (score 0):

Just make another `CSS` class similar to `.main` except for the `background-image` property

```
.someclass
{
    padding: 0px 12px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    min-height: 630px;
    width:auto;
    background-image:url('newbackground.png');

}
```

**Example:**

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="server" class="main"></div>

  protected void initiative_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
  {
     myDiv.CssClass="someclass"
  }
```

**Note: You need to make sure that your div has runat="server" attribute in order to be accessible from code behind.**

Comment: @user1776590 What controls background-image are you trying to change?

Comment: @user1776590 Do you want to change background-image of the body?

Comment: <div class="main">
        
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
            
            
        </div>

Comment: will this change the backgournd on the current page or the one that it goes to as that has a different site.master to the previous page.

Comment: @user1776590 I think the current page.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to change the CSS, then I can recommend [this CSS parser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20450/Simple-CSS-Parser), which will enable you to read in the CSS file, change it, and then write it out again. But as already pointed out, it may be better to change this client-side by setting the style on the relevant html element.

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like:

```
<div class="main" id="mainContainer" runat="server"><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/></div>
```

On the server side, do this:

```
mainContainer.Attributes.Add("style", "background-image('myImage.png')");
```

Or, even beter, you could change the CSS class:

```
mainContainer.Attributes.Add("class", "className");
```

Comment: the line are on the master slide not the page that is running